# Filter bound Datagridview with a list (multiple values)

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a datagridview bound to a MySQL table 'spareparts' using Visual Studio's built in DataSource property. In this datagrid there is a column Part Number. I have a separate list with multiple Part Numbers. Is there a way to filter the datagridview to show all rows where the Part Number matches any Part Number from the list?

I can do it fine for filtering one particular Part Number:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "[Part Number] LIKE '%" + mypartno + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

But I don't know how to do this for multiple part numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to loop through your list and build up a string of

```
OR [Part Number] LIKE [ x ]
```

Otherwise if you don't need the wildcards you can use `IN` instead of `LIKE` :

```
"[Part Number] IN ( 'x', 'y', 'z')"
```

Comment: You have lead me on the right track. I loop through the list and with each loop I add to the query the condition. Is it now possible to have this add another condition to the query? So it filters my list of part numbers, but also filter my list of model numbers and any other field I may need?

Comment: Yes, just add additional `OR` statements for the conditions you need. Or `AND`'s depending on your filtering requirements.

Comment: Great! Nearly there, just one last question and it should be perfect. In some cases the part number is null. How do account for this in the query as if it's null it won't even display the row.

Comment: You'll need to add `AND [part number] IS NOT NULL`

Comment: It might be worth doing a basics tutorial in SQL queries as this will give you an understanding of what is going on behind the scenes and help you work with data in your controls in the future, especially as they get more complex.